# How to name rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case, union

I've got the following query:

```
(SELECT count(ID)/2 FROM people  where Date between '2000' and '2001') 
union
(SELECT count(ID)/3 FROM people where Date between '2002' and '2004') 
union
(SELECT count(ID)/6 FROM people where Date between '2005' and '2010')
```

The numbers are correct. Now I want to give names to the rows to see which people are meant.
I only know how to give names to columns thus far.

EDIT: Plus how would I name the column where the new names are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select (case when date between 2000 and 2001 then '2000-2001'
             when date between 2002 and 2004 then '2002-2004'
             when date between 2005 and 2010 then '2005-2010'
        end) as dt_range,
       (count(*) * 1.0 / 
        (case when date between 2000 and 2001 then 1
              when date between 2002 and 2004 then 2
              when date between 2005 and 2010 then 5
         end) 
       ) as value
from people
group by dt_range;
```

I'm a bit surprised by your choice of denominator.  It is one less than the rate.  I would expect the value to be the complete range.

Assuming you have data for all years, you could express this as:

```
select (case when date between 2000 and 2001 then '2000-2001'
             when date between 2002 and 2004 then '2002-2004'
             when date between 2005 and 2010 then '2005-2010'
        end) as dt_range,
       (count(*) * 1.0 / 
        (max(date) - min(date) + 1)
       ) as value
from people
group by dt_range;
```

Comment: The first gives error 1064 around ```as value``` and the second works but gives just one row. Do you have any ideas what could be wrong with the ifrst one? I got your point witht the denominator and adjusted it.

Comment: The last parenthesis before ```as value``` is one too much. It works and gives the correct results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add one column to the subqueries:

```
select dt_2000_2001 as dt_range, count(id) cnt from people  where date between 2000 and 2001
union all
select dt_2002_2004, count(id) / 2 from people where date between 2002 and 2004 
union all
select dt_2005_2010, count(id) / 5 from people where date between 2005 and 2010
```

I am not convinced that you really need `union` here. If there are rows for every year, you could use a `case` expression to build the groups, and `count(distinct)` to compute the denumerators like so:

```
select
    case when date between 2000 and 2001 then dt_2000_2001
         when date between 2002 and 2004 then dt_2002_2004
         when date between 2005 and 2010 then dt_2005_2010
    end as dt_range,
    count(*) / count(distinct date) cnt
from people
group by dt_range
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second query count will be correct if date column just contains only the dates without full time stamps?

Comment: @AsifMehmood: from the original query that the OP showed, it seems like `date` is actually an integer value, not a `date` or `datetime` - otherwise, the `where` conditions would not make sense anyway.

Comment: You’re right about the date column data type. Thanks!

Comment: I have not figured out why but the ```case statement``` doesn't show the right results

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT: if you do have timestamps, then you should replace all occurences of `date` with `year(date)`.